# Выкусить строку после разделителя

Tags: c#

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var sentence = "dima;roma;masha";
    string strY = sentence.Substring(sentence.IndexOf(";") + 1);
    Console.WriteLine(strY);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Пытаюсь научиться выкусывать части строк. Разделитель - точка с запяток. Данные код выводит roma;masha
Как мне сделать так, чтобы я мог легко указывать какая асть строки после какого разделителя мне нужна?

К примеру мне нужно выкусить:
`dima`

Как подобным кодом выкуcить `masha`?

Про `LastIndexOf` знаю - но это не вариант т.к. строка может содержать 10 значений, а мне нужно разобраться как к примеру пятое значение выкусить

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте так:

```
var parts = sentence.Split(';').ToList();
parts.RemoveAt(1);
var newSentence = string.Join(";", parts);
```

Для старых версий .NET немного менее удобно:

```
var newSentence = string.Join(";", parts.ToArray());
```

Comment: Ругается:
Аргумент "2": преобразование типа из "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>" в "string[]" невозможно (CS1503) - C:\Users\Dima\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\test1\test1\Program.cs:23,37

Comment: @Suliman4: Какая у вас версия .NET?

Comment: Версия .NET 4.5

Comment: Ах да, для `Join` нужен не символ, а строка. Поправил ответ.